# How would the regression tree change with the dataset?

Tags: cart

I stumbled upon the following question:

Given a dataset $S={(x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m)} \in R^d x R$ and positive scale factors $a \in (0, \infty)^d$ and $c \in (0,\infty)$ along with offsets $b \in R^d$ and $d \in R$ we define the transforms $f_{a,b}(x)=(a_1x_1+b_1,...,a_dx_d+b_d)$ and $g_{c,d}(y)=cy+d$. Consider the regression tree corresponding to the greedy recursive partitioning procedure with respect to square error on the dataset S.

Suppose we first transform the dataset to ${(f_{a,b}(x_1), y_1),...,(f_{a,b}(x_m), y_m)}$
then compute the regression tree. Will the computed regression tree change and if so how?
Same question if we transform the dataset to ${(x_1,g_{c,d}(y_1)),...,(x_m,g_{c,d}(y_m))}$

I am not exactly sure how to argue or what the correct answer would be but my intuition tells me that in the first case the regression tree would change since  we are basically modifying the input set that we are using to do the binary splitting so the tree would look different. For the 2nd case, where we only change the y values, the regression tree would be the same with the only modification that the leaf nodes would have different values.

Would this be correct or am I missing something?